# Custom styling TEdit

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm defining a custom style for a `tedit` object wich is on a form.

In the style editor I have add a `tRectangle` to the background property, set its `Align` property to Client, set the fill and stroke color. Then I'd saved the StyleBook and the `tedit` appearence changed properly reflecting the StyleBook settings.

Sadly, when I run the app, though the appearence of the `tedit` is right, clicking on the client area doesn't show the cursor, neither I can input any character. I've already set content, foreground, etc to stay on top, but it doesn't help.

I'm attaching 2 sample images. I really appreciate anyone's help.

Structure

[image]

properties

[image]

Comment: Did you set `HitTest:= False` in `Rectange1Style`? (if true, the rectangle will capture all clicks and make the edit not respond). Also what you call the background property, is actually a component that has got the name `background`. You could simply delete it and use your new rectangle as the background.

Comment: @Hans. Thanks for your tip. I set `HitTest:= False` as you suggested, but still can't put the cursor into the `tEdit`. Do you have any further suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to "send to background" the rectangle?

Comment: @Hans. I deleted the `Background` object & added a `TRectangle`. Set it's `Align` property to `Client`, it's back `Color` property to `Aqua` & sent it to back. All objects but `TRectangle` must `Bring to Front`. All objects with no exception must `Stay on Top `. That was the issue that confused me, because on a video at YouTube, the folk was using  `Stay on Top` for the other objects as an equivalent to `Bring to Front`. In fact, now I realize that the objects are painted in the order that are listed on the `Structure`, so `TRectangle` will be painted first & all the rest on top of it.

Comment: @Hans. I must add that you have to set the `TRectangle's` `HitTest:= False` as you stated before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'RectangleStyle' must be a parent of 'content', 'prompt' and 'buttons' - 
Something like

[image: this]

Comment: I'm wondering how do i start the animation in this example ? (from event ?) by code ?